# How can I get the localized first day of the week in Django?

Tags: python, django, date, localization

I am using `bootstrap-datepicker`. Week start is set with a digit as follows:

```
0 Sunday
1 Monday
2 Tuesday
3 Wednesday
4 Thursday
5 Friday
6 Saturday
```

I need to get the **localised first day of the week from Django**, and turn it into the correct number from `0` to `6` above. Is this possible with Django?

Comment: You can set the locale on bootstrap-datepicker. [Here](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#using-locales) is a demo

Comment: Hi khajvah, is there a way I can confirm that the two use the same list of locales?

Comment: I didn't understand your question. Which "two" are you talking about?

Comment: Django and bootstrap-datepicker. Having looked it up, the moment locales used by bootstrap-datepicker at https://github.com/moment/moment/tree/develop/locale and the Django locales at https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/locale/__init__.py don't match up, so I'll need to stick to setting bootstrap-datepicker manually based on output from Django